# How to analyze jmeter TPS graph

Tags: graph, jmeter, tps

I made a TPS graph using jmeter, but I can't interpret what it means. Please tell me how to interpret the graph

```
request of type get named "A"

threads: 1000
ramp-up period: 100
loop Count: 1
```

1. Active Threads Over Time

[1. image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4gkE.png)

2. Response Times Over Time

[2. image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBgDn.png)

3. Transactions per Second

[3. image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gykzH.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your graphs mean that:

1. You run 1 thread (virtual user)
2. You can reach 10 transactions per second with this 1 thread
3. Average response time is around 100 milliseconds

You might also be interested in:

- [Apache JMeter HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) - an alternative and automated way of generating pretty zoomable charts
- [Apache JMeter Glossary](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html) - so you would understand what do your metrics mean in general
- [Performance Metrics for Websites](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207420665-Performance-Metrics-for-Websites) - so you would understand how to correlate the metrics and what are possible relationships between them